# WCF Service Binding

Tags: .net, wcf-binding

I want to know whether WCFnetTcp binding working on IIS 6.
I it is working, then how to enable netTcp protocol in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

NetTcpBinding cannot be used with IIS 6.

You need to either upgrade to IIS 7/7.5 which has WAS (Windows Process Activation Service), or you need to self-host your WCF service in a console app or Windows NT Service.

**Update:** if you want to self-host a WCF service, you need do basically create an instance of `ServiceHost` and tell it what service to host and what binding to use etc. This can be done via configuration or code.

To get started, read  [How to host a WCF Service in a Managed Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)

Comment: Good. can you guide me for self-hosting with netTcpBinding